# In Tableau, errors occurred while reloading the data source

Tags: excel, tableau-api

While refreshing the data source with live connection, i am facing this issue for Excel datasource.
Field 'load_type' which is included for filtering does not exist.
Field 'none:order_date:qk' which is included for filtering does not exist.

Please provide any clue to resolve this issue.

Comment: These types of errors typically occur when the excel sheet has been modified in some way (in this case tableau has been unable to find those fields on the worksheet when reloading the data).  Errors with live excel connections can also occur if you have the sheet open in excel while Tableau is attempting to access it.  Beyond that, it would be hard to further diagnose your issue without more detail

Comment: The only change is excel sheet exported from different tool. i didn't open excel sheet while refreshing tableau viz and also those fields are there as-is (same fields with same version of excel, only data changes). However, earlier i used to do some filterations using postgres and then export it then refreshing the tableau.now i followed the same process with MS SQL (SSMS) and then exported using import and export wizard. then i tried refreshing the tableau viz. , it was throwing these errors.

Comment: I would compare an Excel sheet of each export to see what looks different. When replacing data sources, the header names in the source data need to match exactly (no renaming, case sensitive) fore tableau to automatically map them. You can also explicitly draw relationships between two data sources using  edit relationships so the replace goes well. Something has changed that is throwing the tableau data interpreter off. Alternatively, you can copy and paste calculated fields to the new data source so that you can recreate from scratch if that is simpler

Comment: I downloaded pgadmin3 (the error is in pgadmin4), even though there is support for this version. I am able to do some filterations in postgres and copy to a csv and then to excel and then to Tableau. This is not a direct fix but for immediate fix since my work halt. Thanks for the quick reply.